# Criar Novo Reporitório - Git / Bitbucket. Git (Could not read from remote repository)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, versionamento, bitbucket

Estou fazendo o tutorial de Ruby on Rails e estou travando em um problema. Já fiz um repositório *hello_app (cap um)*, e agora estou tentando fazer o *toy_app (cap dois)*. Este é o passo a passo do tutorial:

1) Eu criei novo diretório (toy_app) e digitei:

```
"$ bundle install --without production" pra instalar os gems.
```

2) Então, precisamos inserir o toy_app no sistema de versionamento:

```
$ git init

$ git add -A

$ git commit -m "Initialize repository"
```

Feito com sucesso também!

3) Criar repositório no *bitbucket*. Aqui está meu problema. No capitulo um eu já criei um repositório. Agora, vim no *Bitbucket*, criei o novo repositório "toy_app" (não preciso adicionar a "SSH Key", ne?). O *Bitbucket* orienta que seja digitado:

```
$ cd toy_app

$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:MoisesHotmail/toy_app.git

$ git push -u origin --all 

$ git push -u origin --tags
```

Mas quando digitei o segundo comando, apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

> conq: repository does not exist. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
>   the repository exists.

O que eu faço? Não consigo seguir a diante. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que devia ser algum bug, desses que acontecem sem razão. Dei "$ git init" e resolveu. Fiz os comandos de novo e funcionou.

Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode especificar o username que o SSH deve enviar para o repositório remoto como parte da sua url. Coloque o username, seguido por um `@`, antes do hostname do repositório:

```
git remote set-url website abc@***.com:path/to/repo
```